# Select combinations to get from start to finish

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have an array of tickets that contain information about departure and destination:

```
 class Connection
  DB = [
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Berlin"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Barcelona"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Warsaw"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Barcelona"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Paris"},
    {departure: "Paris",  destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "Madrid", destination: "New York"},
    {departure: "Madrid", destination: "Berlin"}
  ].freeze
end
```

I should select combinations to get from start to finish. I.e., for `start = "New York"` and `finish = "Madrid"`, method `find` should return the following:

```
 [
     [
       {dep: "New York", dest: "Madrid"}
     ],
     [
       {dep: "New York", dest: "Berlin"},
       {dep: "Berlin", dest: "Madrid"}
     ],
     [
       {dep: "New York", dest: "Berlin"},
       {dep: "Berlin", dest: "Paris"},
       {dep: "Paris", dest: "Madrid"}
     ]
   ]
```

I solved it in this way:

```
class Connection
  def initialize(start, finish)
    @start  = start
    @finish = finish
    @result = []
  end

  def find(departure = @start, tickets = [])
    search_by_departure(departure).each do |ticket|
      next if tickets.any?{ |t| t[:departure] == ticket[:destination] }
      tickets << ticket
      if ticket[:destination] == @finish
        @result << clean_route(tickets)
      else
        find(ticket[:destination], tickets)
      end
    end
    @result
  end

  private

  def clean_route(route)
    route.reverse.uniq{|r| r[:departure]}.reverse
  end

  def search_by_departure(start)
    DB.select{ |x| x[:departure] == start }
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to solve it.

Comment: Questions of the form "this code works but I'm wondering if it can be better" belong to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, your code will fall into infinite recursion if there are loops in your graph. For example, try adding Paris -> New York to your initial list of tickets and you will see infinite recursion.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. Where do `:dep` and `:dest` come from?

Comment: @abl thanks for this information, I didn't know about Code Review Stack Exchange. Yes, I thought about infinite recursion, I'll check it.

Comment: You should think of this as a directed graph with no cycles. It lends itself well to recursion. If you want to go from A to B, and from A you can go directly to C or D, then all paths from A to B are all paths from C to B, each prepended with A to C, plus all paths from D to B pretended with A to D. Yes, this question belongs on *Code Review*, where you're likely to get more useful answers than you would here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished a course that taught us about [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), which are two methods that are ideal for this type of problem. They are fundamental search techniques in the field of [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), which considers your locations and tickets as **nodes** and **edges** of a **directed graph**.

I went with breadth-first search here. If first explores every possible path just one node deep, storing each of these paths in memory. Then, beginning with the first branch it found, it explores just one step deeper for each unfinished path in memory. It repeats this until all non-cyclic paths are fully explored.

```
edges = [
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Berlin"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Barcelona"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Warsaw"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Barcelona"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Paris"},
    {departure: "Paris",  destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "Madrid", destination: "New York"},
    {departure: "Madrid", destination: "Berlin"}
]

nodes = edges.collect{|edge| edge.values}.reduce(:+).uniq

def find_paths(start_node, end_node, edges)

    #array to hold the unique paths that we find
    solutions = []

    #array to hold all paths that we haven't finished exploring
    path_stack = [[start_node]]

    #keep looping until we've explored all possible non-cyclic paths
    while not path_stack.empty?

        #first, retrieve the path we're exploring for this iteration of the loop
        current_path = path_stack.shift

        #if the path has reached the final destination...
        if current_path[-1] == end_node

            #add it to the solutions
            solutions.push current_path

        #otherwise, keep exploring it
        else

            #get all the children (destinations) of the current path's last node (location)
            last_node_children = edges.select{|edge| edge[:departure] == current_path[-1]}.collect{|edge| edge[:destination]}

            #iterate through each child
            last_node_children.each do |child_node|

                #if the current path doesn't already include this node...
                if not current_path.include? child_node

                    #add the node to the current path and put this path on top of the stack
                    path_stack.push current_path + [child_node]
                end
            end
        end
    end

    solutions
end

p find_paths "New York", "Madrid", edges
```

**Output:**

```
[["New York", "Madrid"], ["New York", "Berlin", "Madrid"], ["New York", "Berlin", "Paris", "Madrid"]]
```

Comment: thanks for detailed description of your solution, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with:

```
links = [
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Berlin"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Barcelona"},
    {departure: "New York", destination: "Warsaw"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Barcelona"},
    {departure: "Berlin", destination: "Paris"},
    {departure: "Paris",  destination: "Madrid"},
    {departure: "Madrid", destination: "New York"},
    {departure: "Madrid", destination: "Berlin"}
  ]

start = "New York"
finish = "Madrid"
```

let's create a more useful data structure:

```
h = links.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  h[g[:departure]] << g[:destination]
end
  # => {"New York"=>["Madrid", "Berlin", "Barcelona", "Warsaw"],
  #     "Berlin"  =>["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Paris"],
  #     "Paris"   =>["Madrid"],
  #     "Madrid"  =>["New York", "Berlin"]}
```

and solve by recursion:

```
def paths(h, so_far, finish)
  so_far = [*so_far]
  h[so_far.last].each_with_object([]) do |city, arr|
    if city == finish
      arr << so_far + [city]
    elsif !so_far.include? city
      arr.concat(paths(h, so_far + [city], finish))
    end
  end
end

paths(h, start, finish)
  #=> [["New York", "Madrid"], ["New York", "Berlin", "Madrid"],
  #    ["New York", "Berlin", "Paris", "Madrid"]]
```

It's easy to create the requested from this array, so I will skip that step.

Notes:

- `so_far = [*so_far]` merely converts `so_far` to an array if it is not one already. The only time it is not an array is when the method is first called with `so_far` being the starting city.
- `elsif !so_far.include? city` prevents cities already visited being visited again, which would create a cycle in the graph.